# Touch event does'nt constantly fire with cancollide false

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a part without cancollide set to true. I want it to slowly damage the player but the touched event only fires when the player is constantly moving. Any way to fix it? Heres the code:

```
local water = workspace.Maps.Surface.Water

function TouchedWater(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").Health -= 0.1
    end
end

water.Touched:Connect(TouchedWater)
```

I have also tried gettouchingparts or something like that. But it did'nt work